# Access null Java object's field without NPE

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, null, java-7

I'm working on an Android project that uses a lot of strange null checking in Java, leading to lines of code like this:

```
if (foo == null || foo.bar == null || foo.bar.foobar == null) {
    return;
}
```

I'm trying to clean it up using the Utility class

```
public class Utility {
    public static boolean allNotNull(Object... objects) {
        for (Object object : objects) {
            if (objectIsNull(object)) { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean anyAreNull(Object... objects) {
        return !allNotNull(objects);
    }

    private static boolean objectIsNull(Object object) {
        try {
            return object == null;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Using this class, I'd like to simplify the code to

```
if (Utility.areAnyNull(foo.bar.foobar)) {
    return;
}
```

Unfortunately, this is crashing before entering the areAnyNull function when A is null. Is there any way to prevent the function from crashing, without wrapping a try catch statement around each of my if (Utility...) calls? Alternatively, is there a better way to go about cleaning up my if statements checking if something is null?

Comment: From your `java-7` tag I assume Java 8 is not an option?

Comment: Yeah, using Android. I could use the backported Java 8 optionals, but they don't end up making the code any easier to read.

Comment: If using Groovy is an option for you, they have a null-safe operator: `foo?.bar?.foobar`.

Comment: Afraid not. Can't use anything but Java 7 for this project, as it's not a personal project. I wish the client would let us switch to Groovy or Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any native syntactical way to do that in Java. But if you have Java 8, you can use [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) to do something similar:

```
boolean areAnyNull = !Optional.of(foo)
        .map(foo -> foo.bar)
        .map(bar -> bar.foobar)
        .isPresent();
```

Comment: I'm using Java 7 (it's an Android project), and this actually makes the code harder to read, and doesn't seem to add any additional benefits. I'm basically trying to achieve the `if let` syntax from Swift as closely as possible in Java, by exiting the function if the values are null, and otherwise assigning them to variables.

Comment: @communistWatermelon, `Optional` does provide other utilities besides `ifPresent()`. That was just the closest answer to your specific question.

Comment: It definitely forces the user to think of and explicitly add null safety, but Java's implementation does nothing to help the user use the non-null value. `ifPresent()` is basically just `if (!= null)`, `or()` is just `if (== null) { doThing; }`. The map functions are nice, but not really applicable in this case. Java Optionals just don't seem as useful as Kotlin/Swift/Groovey's implementations, IMO.